# Siesta: Component Query assertion doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, siesta

I am playing around with Siesta and some built in assertions.

I came across a problem with the `elementIsNotEmpty()` assertion.
I want to check if after typing an empty string in a login field, the field is really empty and nothing is displayed in it.

So mein Test-Chain looks something like this:

```
t.it("Login with non valid Data", function(t) {
    t.diag("Failing the Login"),
    t.chain(
        // Login
        t.loginFunction("", "alsoWrong"),
        {
            waitFor: 10000
        },
        t.elementIsNotEmpty(">>textfield[itemId=fldPassword]")
    );
});
```

In My LoginFunction i work with the Same componentquery element, as you can see here:

```
{
                action: 'type',
                target: ">>textfield[itemId=fldName]",
                text: user,
                desc: "Type in username"
            },
```

I get a warning at the line where i use `elementIsNotEmpty`, which says:

> WARN: Your component query: "textfield[itemId=fldPassword]" returned no components

Wheres the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

> In My LoginFunction i work with the Same componentquery element, as you can see here:

No we can't.

The one that complains looks for a textfield with `itemId:"fIdPassword"`, while the working example looks for a textfield with `itemId:"fIdName"`

If that is not what the problem is about (i.e. just a typo), please show us the code that you are testing as well.
With just the test itself, there is no way to tell if the tested code is working.